# Aggregate functions in S3 Select

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-s3-select

[Amazon's S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/selecting-content-from-objects.html) allows a user to write SQL against S3 objects, but there's insufficient documentation around what standard SQL functionality is supported.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-aggregate.html), Amazon S3 Select supports `AVG`, `COUNT`, `MAX`, `MIN`, and `SUM`. But when I run any aggregate query I get an error like

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
>   (UnsupportedSqlOperation) when calling the SelectObjectContent
>   operation: Unsupported SQL operation GROUP BY. Please check the
>   service documentation for supported operations.

Here's some code to reproduce:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.select_object_content(Bucket='my-bucket', Key='object.csv', 
    ExpressionType='SQL', Expression="select ID, count(*) from s3object group by s.ID ",
    InputSerialization = {'CSV':{"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}, 'CompressionType': 'GZIP'},
    OutputSerialization = {'CSV':{}})

event_stream = response['Payload']
with open('output', 'wb') as f:
    for event in event_stream:
        if 'Records' in event:
            data = event['Records']['Payload']
            f.write(data)
```

Comment: If possibly supports the Aggregate functions without a `GROUP BY`. This would aggregate all the results into just one line. (I haven't tried it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per John's comment, aggregate functions are only supported without a `GROUP BY`.

Here are a few caveats and pointers

- You can obviously filter the set you want to perform your aggregation across, using a `WHERE` or `LIMIT` clause.
- Everything is a string, so any **numeric** operation requires a `CAST`, e.g. `sum(cast(my_col as float))`
- Mixed results using `MAX` and `MIN` on interpreting numerical columns as strings, i.e. without a cast; it initially succeeded but after further processing I couldn't reproduce that success
- Can't perform aggregate functions in the same query as non-aggregate functions, and the error message is cryptic: `A column name or a path provided in the query expression does not exist`

Comment: Did you find a way to mimic a group by?

Comment: No, I don't think it exists. Stream the data into an aggregation routine, or just use Athena.